# How to select specific element from same name element group jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Recently I'm getting stuck on this. I have a set of text boxes that have the same name like this:

```
<p><input type="text" name="test[]" /></p>
<p><input type="text" name="test[]" /></p>
<p><input type="text" name="test[]" /></p>
```

So what I need to do is select the 2nd element of group. I tried to alert

`$('input[name="test['2']"]').val();` but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: yes this is better im sorry by mistakenly i did reject ur edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) :

```
$('input[name="test[]"]').eq(1).val();
```

or [:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) :

```
$('input[name="test[]"]:eq(1)').val();
```

Note that the index is zero-based in both cases